# Proof by contradiction problem

Tags: integers

How can I prove that the statement:

'there is no integer, $n$, such that $4n^2 + 1 < 4n$'

is true, by contradiction?

I greatly appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: $f(x)=4x^2-4x+1$ is increasing on $\left[1,\infty\right)$ and $f(1)=1>0$

Comment: @Tucker Likewise for $(-\infty,0]$

Comment: @ignoramus it is decreasing on that interval. Take a derivative and check the sign for $x\leq 0$

Comment: @Tucker I meant that the result still holds for the negative integers.

Comment: It is true that $4n<1+4n^2$ for $n<0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that there is an $n$ for which $4n^2+1<4n$. Then

$\begin{align}
4n^2-4n+1<0 &\implies\\
(2n-1)^2<0
\end{align}$

which is a contradiction because $(2n-1)$ is an integer and squares of integers can never be negative.

Comment: See, I'm such a noob. I had (2n-1)^2 but didn't see that step. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assume for the sake of contradiction that

$$4n^2+1<4n$$

Well it is certainly the case that

$$4n^2<4n^2+1$$

So we have

$$4n^2<4n^2+1<4n$$

$$4n^2<4n$$
$$4n^2-4n<0$$

$$4n(n-1)<0$$

So $n$ and $n-1$ must be of opposite sign

$n>n-1$ So we take $n-1<0$ and $n>0$ from which we get $0<n<1$ which contradicts our original assumptions that $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The question states $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ not $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So there is a step where you say if $n = 0$ then $0^2<0$ which is a contradiction, and if $n < 0$ then a square is less than a negative which is also a contradiction.

Comment: The set of all integers includes negative numbers

Comment: Thanks . I overlooked that detail but believe I have been been able to salvage the proof.